# Typesetting Visual Analogue Scales for questionnaire (within enumerated list)

Tags: lists, enumerate

I'm trying to make a series of Visual Analogue Scales (VAS) ([1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_analogue_scale)) as `\item` s inside an enumerated list for a research questionnaire.

I'd like to make all the lines the same (user-definable) length, with each line vertically aligned about the centre of the page. I want the corresponding text labels at the ends of each line to be vertically aligned centrally below the ends of the corresponding line. The text labels for each `\item` are of differing length.

I've attached an ugly MWE using tables within the enumerated list environment to show the kind of effect I'm trying to achieve, but the lengths and alignments of successive lines are inconsistent, and the endings of each line do not align with the centre of the corresponding text labels.

Is there a neat and flexible way to do the above in LaTeX; ideally using standard LaTeX packages?

Many thanks

```
enter 
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item{How do you feel today?\\ (please put a cross on the line below)\\
\begin{table}[!h]\centering
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
\cmidrule{2-3}
Utterly& \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad& \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad& Ecstatically\\
Miserable& \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad& \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad& Happy \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
 \\ \\}

\item{How was the service today?\\(please put a cross on the line below)\\
\begin{table}[!h]\centering
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
\cmidrule{2-3}
The worst& \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad& \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad& Absolutely\\
I've ever experienced& \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad& \quad \quad \quad \quad\quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad& Brilliant\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
 \\ \\}

\item{etc. \ldots}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not use `table` if you don't want it to float. So I removed that part. Then you can specify the with of the column by using `p{<width>}`, meaning paragraph. In such narrow columns as here it looks strange to have text stretched out to fill the lines, so I used `array` to specify a version with ragged right margin.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcommand\ScaleLine[2]{%
  \strut\newline (please put a cross on the line below)\vspace*{1em}\newline
  \begin{tabular}{@{}L{0.2\linewidth}p{0.6\linewidth}L{0.2\linewidth}@{}}
    #1 & \rule[-5pt]{0.4pt}{10pt}\hrulefill\rule[-5pt]{0.4pt}{10pt} & #2
  \end{tabular}
}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item How do you feel today?
  \ScaleLine{Utterly Miserable}{Ecstatically Happy}
  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\item How was the service today?
  \ScaleLine{The worst I've ever experienced}{Absolutely Brilliant}
  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\item{etc. \ldots}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**--EDIT--**

To get the text centered beneath the end points of the line try to define the `\ScaleLine` as follows (two rows in the tabular instead).

```
\newcommand\ScaleLine[2]{%
  \strut\newline (please put a cross on the line below)\vspace*{1em}\newline
  \begin{tabular}{@{}p{0.15\linewidth}@{}p{0.15\linewidth}@{}p{0.4\linewidth}@{}p{0.15\linewidth}@{}p{0.15\linewidth}@{}}
    & \multicolumn{3}{@{}p{0.7\linewidth}@{}}{\rule[-5pt]{0.4pt}{10pt}\hrulefill\rule[-5pt]{0.4pt}{10pt}} & \\[10pt]
    \multicolumn{2}{@{}P{0.3\linewidth}@{}}{#1} && \multicolumn{2}{@{}P{0.3\linewidth}@{}}{#2}
  \end{tabular}
}
```

Alternatively two lines in a `\parbox` (to prevent page split) can be used.

```
\newcommand\ScaleLine[2]{%
  \strut\newline (please put a cross on the line below)\vspace*{1em}\newline
  \parbox{\linewidth}{%
    \rule{0.15\linewidth}{0pt}
    \rule[-5pt]{0.4pt}{10pt}\hrulefill\rule[-5pt]{0.4pt}{10pt}%
    \rule{0.15\linewidth}{0pt}\vspace*{7pt}\newline
       \parbox{0.3\linewidth}{\centering #1}\hfill\parbox{0.3\linewidth}{\centering #2}
  }
}
```

Both alternatives gives about the same output:
[image]

Comment: Many thanks for your rapid and elegant solution Stefan.
Is it possible to change the text labels so that their content is vertically aligned centrally (instead of ragged right); their position is below the ends of the line (rather than vertically aligned centre), and the centre of the text boxes are horizontally aligned centre with the ends of the scale lines?
(sorry - I didn't describe my desired alignment correctly in my original post: hope this makes sense!)

Comment: See edit above. You can make two rows in the table, one for the line and one for the text. To get the text centered at the line ends some manipulating with `\multicolumn` can be used.

Comment: When I think of it, it is probably easier to do the edit using two different lines without the table.

Comment: Amazing! And also has taught me a lot about how to write \newcommands and use \array and \parbox. Thank you! Marked solved.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure if I get your wishes right, but do you mean something like this?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item How do you feel today? (please put a cross on the line below)

Utterly \hrulefill\ Ecstatically

Miserable \hrulefill\ Happy

\item If you need longer entries.

\begin{minipage}{2.5cm}
This is the left entry of the line.
\end{minipage}
\hrulefill
\begin{minipage}{2.5cm}\raggedleft
This is the right entry of the line.
\end{minipage}

\item etc. \ldots
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Not quite the effect I wanted, but thanks!